# Carthage0.18.1 unable to find shared dependency scheme xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, git, xcode7, carthage

I am trying to use Carthage to build one of my own framework uploaded on git and use the same with in my native app project but finding some issue in that.
*** Skipped building sdkName due to the error:
Dependency sdkName has no shared framework schemes for any of the platforms: iOS

I have already checked following things-

> > schemes under Manage Schemes are already shared and pushed to git. Please see attached screenshot of git commits showing xcuserdata & xcshareddata.[schemes git n xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGQFU.jpg)
> >
> > I have checked git status of my framework as well, it has no untracked files.
> >     Untracked files:
> >       (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
../sdk.zip
```

My cartfile has:
git "https://gitlab.carot.com/name/sdkName.git" "master"

Building using command carthage update --platform iOS

Please suggest where the problem could be. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post a screenshot of your schemas "build" settings

Comment: I have edited my question and attached the build settings schemas.Thanks !

Comment: You did post Build Settings and Build Phases. I meant the settings within your scheme. Sorry for being mistakable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Build Settings screen-shot you can see, that there is no framework target for MyFramework (like there is for ...-QA, ...-dev):

[image]

To fix this:

- Click the "+" button (see image) to add a new target
- Choose "iOS" -> "Cocoa Touch Framework" or "Cocoa Touch Static Library" (depending on your needs)
- For every sourceFile.swift of MyFramework, make sure the "Target Membership" is set:

[image]

- In "Manage Schemes", tick "shared":

### [image]